# How to post a JSON array using retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

How to post `JSON` array using `retrofit2` in Android?
here i attatch format of data

```
{
     "lat": 11.024,
     "lon": 75.054,
     "maxdistance": 5000,
     "amintyArray": [
     "5ad251cfe601aa22a8f48d98",
     "5ad251dae601aa22a8f48d99",
     "5ad251ece601aa22a8f48d9a"
     ],
     "starArray": [
     "5ad252b1e601aa22a8f48db1"

    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

make request pojo class like below it define array or single value..

```
public class JsonData {
    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    private long createdAt;

    @SerializedName("firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    @SerializedName("users")
    private List<User> users;

    public long getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(long createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

after that make api for requesting ..

```
@POST("linke")
Call<Response> passJsonData(@Body JsonData jsonData);
```

after insert data into Json data object then pass only json data.

Comment: i have created POJO classes. but i dont know how to give  post request in activity. i had done json object format data like this    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("name", "xxx"); 
jsonObj.put("surname", "yy");        how can post my datas json array. please help me

Answer (score 0):

pojo class like blow..

```
public class Example {
@SerializedName("lat")
@Expose
private Double lat;
@SerializedName("lon")
@Expose
private Double lon;
@SerializedName("maxdistance")
@Expose
private Integer maxdistance;
@SerializedName("amintyArray")
@Expose
private List<String> amintyArray = null;
@SerializedName("starArray")
@Expose   
private List<String> starArray = null;
public Double getLat() {
return lat;
}
public void setLat(Double lat) {
this.lat = lat;
 }
public Double getLon() {
return lon;
}
public void setLon(Double lon) {
this.lon = lon;
}
public Integer getMaxdistance() {
return maxdistance;
}
public void setMaxdistance(Integer maxdistance) {
this.maxdistance = maxdistance;
}
public List<String> getAmintyArray() {
return amintyArray;
}
public void setAmintyArray(List<String> amintyArray) {
this.amintyArray = amintyArray;
}
public List<String> getStarArray() {
return starArray;
}
public void setStarArray(List<String> starArray) { 
this.starArray = starArray;
}
}
```